# ASP.NET MVC Editor Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a question about Editor Templates. For example I have a model with date field, product prize field and weight of product field. I have successfully created Editor Templates for DateTime and Decimal. I'm given to understand that when I use EditorFor for any field it takes template depending on a data type of the field.

So when I use: `EditorFor(m=>m.DateOfBirth)` which is DateTime format it looks for DateTime template in EditorTemplates folder and `EditorFor(m=>m.ProductPrice)` which is double it looks for Double template, etc.)

Question is how can I differ that I want to use one Decimal template with string format `##0.00` for (double)ProductPrize and another template with format `##0.0000` for (double)ProductWeight?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to use an overload of `EditorFor`, which accepts template name as second parameter, like:

```
EditorFor(m=>m.ProductPrice, "PriceEditorTemplate")
```

More info: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414.aspx)

Comment: Beat me to it, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick answer. It works like a charm. I think I will use this one since It's easier to edit without need to compile the project again once you've published the site.

Answer (score 5):

Define it in your model using the **UIHint** attribute:

```
[UIHint("MySpecificEditorTemplate")]
public ProductPrice {get;set;}
```

And EditorFor will use the *MySpecificEditorTemplate.cshtml* for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick answer. This works also but I will use Sergeys solution since this is compiled in dll library which makes it harder to edit once the site is up and running